# url routing catch-all not workin

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, url-routing

I am routing all requests myself. I have written the pattern as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("{*all}", new URLRouter()));
```

But when request for www.example.com/styles/site.css arrive, it is not caught by URLRouter handler.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. The issue appeared that all requests were passing to my URLRouter handler but the request for static contents (such as styles/site.css) are not collected by url-parameter-variable "all" in "{*all}", and all was containing null, although strange thing is that, this request was contained in requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url. So, I am using requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url than url-parameter-variable "all".

Answer (score 1):

What IIS version is installed? Looks like static file requests are not even reach ASP.NET ISAPI filter. This is default behavior in IIS6 and IIS7 Classic mode application pool.

**Update:** Set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in Web.config (modules section)

Comment: Actually, I think this is the default behavior in IIS 6 and IIS 7 no matter what application pool is being used.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your response.This is windows azure WebRole project. Azure uses IIS7. how can I change this behavior? so that all requests, including static content requests are handled by my module URLRouter.

Comment: Thanks Artem and Abatishchev, runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is already set :(, and catch-all is not getting all requests :S, it is set as follows, in web.config: <configuration>
  ...
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: I have even set RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true; in ApplicationStart before RouteTable.Routes.Add(
                        new Route("{*all}", new URLRouter())
                        );

Comment: Maybe you could implement static files routing with `URL Rewrite` module: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573358.aspx